# reset password on production with use the devise, unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, openssl, production-environment, unicorn

If I try to reset password I see: **We're sorry, but something went wrong.**
Then I see to my logs:
poruction.log

```
Sent mail to achempion@gmail.com (238ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 610ms

OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname does not match the server certificate):
```

In my production.rb I set the 
`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '178.79.153.194' }`

and openssl version is `OpenSSL 1.0.0g 18 Jan 2012`

I reset password via devise gem

Comment: Do you receive the mail at your Gmail address? Is the URL after you request the password reset on the correct host?

Comment: to  Buck Doyle: My mail is empty and you see this `Sent mail to achempion@gmail.com (238ms)` in log. But what mean `hostname does not match the server certificate`? my hostname or something else

Comment: to Ashitaka: I have only ip and it must work, but no :(

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. I forgot to configure ActionMailer.
[link tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration)